# Rails - error could not find file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in irb and trying to clean up some code I downloaded.

I am running this:

```
require '/Users/alexgenadinik/projects/cmply/cmply-app/lib/app/social/linkedin/linkedin.rb'
```

and it works fine. That file contains this:

```
require File.join(File.expand_path("../",__FILE__),"init")
require 'oauth'

module LinkedIn
  puts "helllllooooo"

  class << self

    #logger.debug "....teeest"
    attr_accessor :token, :secret, :default_profile_fields

    # config/initializers/linkedin.rb (for instance)
    #
    # LinkedIn.configure do |config|
    #   config.token = 'consumer_token'
    #   config.secret = 'consumer_secret'
    #   config.default_profile_fields = ['education', 'positions']
    # end
    #
    # elsewhere
    #
    # client = LinkedIn::Client.new
    def configure
      yield self
      true
    end
  end

  #root_path = File.expand_path("../../../../../",__FILE__)

  autoload :Api,     File.join(LINKED_IN_LOAD_PATH,"linked_in/api.rb") #"linked_in/api"
  autoload :Client,  File.join(LINKED_IN_LOAD_PATH,"linked_in/client.rb") #"linked_in/client"
  autoload :Mash,    File.join(LINKED_IN_LOAD_PATH,"linked_in/mash.rb") #"linked_in/mash"
  autoload :Errors,  File.join(LINKED_IN_LOAD_PATH,"linked_in/errors.rb") #"linked_in/errors"
  autoload :Helpers, File.join(LINKED_IN_LOAD_PATH,"linked_in/helpers.rb") #"linked_in/helpers"
  autoload :Search,  File.join(LINKED_IN_LOAD_PATH,"linked_in/search.rb") #"linked_in/search"

end
```

But when I try to run a command like this:

```
client = LinkedIn::Client.new('key', 'key')
```

I get this error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- linked_in/helpers/authorization
    from /Users/alexgenadinik/projects/cmply/cmply-app/lib/app/social/linkedin/linked_in/helpers/authorization.rb:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/alexgenadinik/projects/cmply/cmply-app/lib/app/social/linkedin/linked_in/client.rb:2
    from (irb):2
```

so it points to line 2 of client.rb which starts like this:

```
require 'cgi'
require File.join(LINKED_IN_LOAD_PATH, "linked_in","helpers/authorization")
```

and line 4 of authorization.rb which starts like this:

```
module LinkedIn
  module Helpers

    module Authorization
```

By the way, should I read the error message from the top, or should I start reading from the bottom to see where the error appeared first?

Help much appreciated. I am not sure why it is giving the error.

Comment: try changing all the autoload to require just to see if it's a dependency not being picked up, not sure if autoload can work if there  is a require client.rb,  kind of a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dir your file is in is "linkedin", but the dirs you are requiring from are "linked_in", you should change the name of the actual dir to linked_in, since that aligns with naming conventions.

That aside, I'm pretty sure Rails adds all directories under app into the load path. So you should be able to just say `require 'linked_in/linked_in'` (assuming you change both the dir and file names) and then you can probably do the same thing with all the autoloads, and get rid of the `File.expand_path ...` stuff.

Comment: thanks ...little confused..which is the file in which I should add the require 'linked_in/linked_in'  ?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I'm pretty sure where you use autoload, you can replace the expanded paths like `autoload :Api,     File.join(LINKED_IN_LOAD_PATH,"linked_in/api.rb")` with `autoload :Api, "linked_in/api.rb"`